# When calculating a distance from a city, how can I factor in the approximate size (physical area) of the city?

Tags: geocoding

I'm building a store locator based on in-house geocoding data.  Effectively I need to query stories near City X or Zip Y within a certain radius.  The data sets I'm working with are relatively comprehensive and include things such as population.

One issue is that large cities (Los Angeles for example) are many miles in radius so you could be within the city but miles from the coordinate we have loaded.

Is there a rule of thumb, or a free data feed which would list an approximate radius of a city, or perhaps even outlines of the city points?

Also, assuming I have a shape defining the city what calculation would I use to say "stores within X miles of this area"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately we didn't implement this feature, but before it was cancelled I had a fair amount of success using the below approach:

- Finding coordinates for the city itself, as well as all zip codes of the city
- "Connecting the dots" of all the above coordinates to create a polygon of the (very rough shape of the city)
- Checking if the user's input coordinate was within the given range of the polygon

The above approach worked relatively well and may have ultimately developed into a sound solution with some more enhancements and tuning.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the zip codes and latitude/longitude of the stores, instead of the cities? You know the addresses of the stores, so use its zip code, look up the coordinates, and calculate the distance from the origin zip code. Then it wouldn't matter how big the city is, because big cities have many zip codes, but each store has its own zip code.

It would only be a problem for states with big zip codes like Texas, but then there is likely not more than 1 store per zip code anyways so not a big deal.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, and one I haven't thought of.  ZipCodes still couldn't be a complete solution, as many communities do not have their own zip code (our zipcode database has about 50k records, whereas our cities database has about 125k)--however the zipcode could be weighted above the city when its available

Comment: What are you talking about? Every address in the US has a zip code. Every community too. You can buy a zip code / latitude/longitude database from the USPS.com. Some zip codes are bigger than cities.

Comment: Many communities share a single zip code, in which case the USPS database contains only the entry for the "main" city assigned to the zipcode

Comment: You don't use the city assigned to the zip code, you use the latitude and longitude of the center of the zip code. What kind of stores are we talking about here? Are you going to have 10 stores per zip code? Are these stores like Starbucks? If it is a Walmart, geocode off the zip code. If Starbucks, you have to geocode off the exact address.